# iOS reverting to expanded keyboard on certain pattern inputs

Tags: ios, html, forms, input

I'm trying to design an input that is limited to 8 characters of any value 0 through 9. Seems simple enough, right?

So, I use this:

```
<input type="number" id="test4" min="0" max="99999999" pattern="\d*">
```

And things work perfectly - with a simple caveat. The max number is not being respected. So, I tried these:

```
<input type="number" id="test2" min="0" max="99999999" pattern="\d{0,8}">
<input type="number" id="test3" min="0" max="99999999" pattern="[0-9]{0,8}">
```

Both of these two revert the iOS keyboard back to the expanded entry and not just the 10 digits. What am I missing? How can I get this input to display the 10-digit iOS keyboard and also be restricted to 8 digits?

(I know that I could simply use JS to cap the entry, but I was trying to avoid that)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="8" pattern="\d*">
```